# is it possible to detect when a brpoplpush has occured and log an event?

Tags: python, events, redis

Is it possible to detect when a brpoplpush has occurred in redis and do something when it does ? in my case I just want to add a note to our logs.

Before my change the python worker snipped looked as follows

```
 while True:
    _redis.brpoplpush(global_waiting_queue, local_waiting_queue)
    logger.info("Moving job from global queue (%s) to local queue (%s)", global_waiting_queue, local_waiting_queue)
```

I wanted to add a heartbeat function so that I could monitor my worker.

```
 while True:
   _redis.brpoplpush(global_waiting_queue, local_waiting_queue, 5)
   queue_worker_heartbeat(_redis, queue_worker_key)
```

is it possible to do something along the following lines

```
   while True:
     action = _redis.brpoplpush(global_waiting_queue, local_waiting_queue, 5)
    if action:
      logger.info("Moving job from global queue to local queue")
    queue_worker_heartbeat(_redis, queue_worker_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a notification using [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications)

By default this feature is disabled.
To activate the list event notifications you should set the following line in your redis configuration file:

```
notify-keyspace-events "Kl"
```

'K' means you want ot be notified of keyspace events, 'l' of list events.

BRPOPLPUSH generates an rpop event and an lpush event:

```
__keyspace@0__:myotherlist lpush
__keyspace@0__:mylist rpop
```

To be notified you must subscribe to the channel

```
psubscribe '__key*__:*'
```

It will send you events like:

```
   __keyspace@0__:mykey rpop
   __keyspace@0__:rpop mykey
```

You can narrow the notifications by using a more precise pattern. By example:

```
psubscribe '__keyspace@0__:mykey'
```

will ensure you are notified only when a command is applied to the key 'mykey' in the database 0.